# translate animation

Tags: android

I want an image to move horizontally.
i.e image should move from left end bottom corner to right end bottom corner once.
No need to come back again to left end bottom corner.

The piece of code which I tried was

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

<translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="200%p" 
android:duration = "2000"/>
</set>
```

this moves the image from left till right. But its again coming to the left side.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I got it...instead of using that animation xml file, I wrote inside java file.

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500,0, 0);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
myImage.startAnimation(animation);
myImage.setVisibility(0);
```

Now the image moves from left to right and then it gets invisible...hence animated!!! :)

Comment: I don't know why that code works. Doesn't make a lot of sense. Try using `View.VISIBLE` in the `setVisibility()` method.

Comment: setVisibility(0) sometimes its not working...i dont know y...I have kept View.INVISIBLE now, which works........

Comment: actually, INVISIBLE is int == 1, VISIBLE == 0, gone ==2, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility) 
**I too had problems with setVisibility in code, so I put View.VISIBLE/View.INVISIBLE in .setVisibility**

Comment: Mine keeps jumping back to where it was originally? I thought the question was to translate, and then stay where it is? setFillAfter(true); isn't keeping the image where it's supposed to

Comment: This code works in the case you invisible the view after animation. TranslateAnimation in android does not change the real position of the view. Use ObjectAnimator instead.

Answer (score 84):

You've fallen victim to the great misunderstanding everyone first makes about Android animations: the animated `ImageView` (or whatever kind of view) *isn't actually moving*  (or scaling or rotating or fading). It's all a trick... an animation is essentially some last-minute instructions to the screen composition engine to offset the view by x/y, rotate by z, etc. The view's underlying position / size / angle / alpha never really changes.

Therefore when the animation ends your image appears to snap back to the starting point,  because it never actually left it.

That said, you can achieve what you want in a simple way by adding `android:fillAfter="true"` to your `<translate>` tag. Just bear in mind that the image hasn't *really* moved. If you need to update your layout at animation end, hook up an [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) and do it in `onAnimationEnd()`.

Comment: Hi Reuben, I tried with android:fillAfter="true"...but its the same as before...then i tried with onAnimationEnd(). I gave visibility of the image as invisible...but still the same thing is happening...any clue on what I have done wrong?

Comment: Probably because you were using a <set> but it hardly matters now.

Comment: Why doesn't it matter? Some code would have made this a lovely answer

Comment: It _is_ a lovely answer.

Comment: This is the only post that I find about usage of `fillAfter` in all of web. Tnx. I don't really understand about  `image hasn't really moved`!! If I have a button and move it to new position, you say that  button hasn't really moved. Ok, but all actions, view itself, everything of button is in new place. Touching in old place does nothing. So what does that mean?

Answer (score 20):

Translate Animation can change the visual appearance of an object, but they cannot change the objects themselves. That is, if you apply a translate animation to a view, it would move to a new position, but its click events would not get fired; the click events would still get fired at its previous position.

This happens because the view is still at its original position. In order to overcome this, we can use ObjectAnimation which actually moves an object.
Object Animation is the only animation which actually moves an object.

You can create Translate animation using ObjectAnimator.

```
ObjectAnimator transAnimation= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, propertyName, fromX, toX);
transAnimation.setDuration(3000);//set duration
transAnimation.start();//start animation
```

view -this is the view on which animation is to be applied
propertyName-The property being animated.
FromX,toX-A set of values that the animation will animate between over time.

Comment: using your link in this answer to drive traffic is frowned upon! Might be better to include a summary quote from that link in here to prevent link rot!

Comment: ObjectAnimator is introduced from android 11. So, on previous version of android, you must use a unofficial library. This is a the NineOldAndroids library which you can find all animation API of android 11 and use with all of other android versions: http://nineoldandroids.com/