# Is it possible to remove(slide off) view from screen? Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Is it possible to remove view from screen? Android

For example I have some layout, which contains 3 layouts;

```
layout_1 layout_2 layout_3
```

Is it possible to click on layout_1, and move it away from screen, and you'll receive visible

```
layout_2 layout_3
```

Thanks in advance.

**upd:** The problem is, that I need to slide off this view smoothly. Looks like a sidebar in Facebook. But another thing is, that other two layouts after removing layout_1 should be stretched to fit parent layout.

Comment: What do you mean by smoothly. It fading out/sliding off screen?

Comment: @Doomsknight sorry for poor English. Yes, I'm talking about sliding off. I'll update the question. Thanks

Comment: I dont know much about animating views Im afraid, but I believe this is what you are looking for. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html Here is an SO question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213393/translate-animation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the view an id.

then do

```
(LinearLayout) linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_1);
linLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

(Cast it to what ever type it is.)

Or do it directly with:

```
findViewById(R.id.layout_1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Edit:** Following your new info and the question/answer I have commented:

```
(LinearLayout) linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_1);
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500,0, 0); //May need to check the direction you want.
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
linLayout.startAnimation(animation);
linLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You might need something more advanced if you want the other 2 to take the space up gradually too.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there's one problem. I've described it in update.

Comment: @Division_Bell as long as you use `View.GONE` and your views are weighted, it will fill the space. Dont use `View.INVISIBLE` because it will still take space up.

Comment: How views will be weighted? I need layout_2 to be the same size as before, and layout_3 streched to fit the free space.

Comment: Then just leave layout_2 as wrap content, or what ever it is at the moment, and change layout_3 to `match_parent` That should be enough. Animations: stackoverflow.com/questions/4213393/translate-animation

Comment: @Division_Bell Ive added some animation code from the other question/answer. Im no expert on it though, so it might need tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply use [`removeView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've didn't explained in details, so please check update.

Comment: Ok, you can use the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) class, animate this transition yourself, or use can rewrite everything to use Fragments to take advantage of its transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are wanting to completely change the view and function of the page. In this case you should either be starting a new activity or look into fragments and the fragment manager.

**EDIT**

Ok if you have the different Views as 3 different fragments you can use the fragment manager to inflate and remove them like so

```
FragmentTransaction ft_main = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//note the following line sets the fragment Tag to "layout_1_fragment" you can
//use this to retrive and dismiss it later
ft_main.replace(R.id.WhateverViewYoureInflatingInto, new Layout_1_Fragment(), "layout_1_fragment");
ft_main.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft_main.commit();
```

to remove the fragment do the following:

```
FragmentTransaction ft_main = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft_main.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("layout_1_fragment"));
ft_main.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft_main.commit();
```

using this code you can dynamically inflate and remove fragments from your screen.

Note: the fragment isn't destroyed when you remove it so if you want to reattach the fragment I suggest checking to see if

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("layout_1_fragment") == null
```

and if not reusing the existing fragment

Comment: In my case I have layout_1 as a Fragment, layout_2 as a simple View and layout_3 as a Fragment as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `OnClickListener` and `View.setVisibility(int)`.