# Verify ImageView is rotated by RotateAnimation

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I have an ImageView that is rotated using RotateAnimation(). I am writing a test case where I want to test that after a button is clicked this view is rotated. So I thought that I can get the rotation angle before the click and after it to check the difference:

```
oldRotationDegrees = view.getRotation();
//click that button and wait for 3 seconds
assertTrue(Math.abs(view.getRotation() - oldRotationDegrees) > 0);
```

However this difference is always 0, because getRotation() always returns 0. I have checked that there is really a rotation visible, so it seems that RotateAnimation() doesn't affect the value returned by getRotation().

So how can I verify that the image has been rotated after the button is pressed?

In case it matters, I am using Robotium for these tests.

**Update**: I am now testing also with robolectric (unit tests) and the behaviour is (without surprise) the same.

**Update 2**: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213493/2160877 explains why this happens.

Comment: post animation code. possible `setFillAfter(true)` could be used to resolve this.

Comment: @r2DoesInc When the button is clicked there are a sequence of RotateAnimation() started(with different end degrees) and it is rotating until the button is clicked again. So I don't think setFillAfter(true) will help to resolve the issue that I have which is just to verify (in a test environment) that the rotation has started.

Comment: fill after sets the animation properties to the view from how i understand it. without it, the animation only applies to how the view is visibly shown. give it a shot.

Comment: I have just checked the code and it already contains `mAnimation.setFillEnabled(true); mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);`

Comment: Check if the width of the view also returns 0, please

Comment: @valbertos The width value returned is not 0

Comment: @helleye did you find a solution to this problem? I am seeing the exact same behavior, getRotation() keeps returning null even after the image is successfully rotated by 180 degrees.

Comment: @AntonCherkashyn Not yet... So I skip testing this, unfortunately.