# Translation Animation not working

Tags: android, translate-animation

> I tried to do a simple animation from **bottom left corner to right center** and then to **center of the screen**

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidthPx = size.x;
    screenHeightPx = size.y;

   final TranslateAnimation slideFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(screenWidthPx, screenWidthPx/2, screenHeightPx, screenHeightPx);
    slideFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    slideFromRight.setStartOffset(300);
    slideFromRight.setDuration(600);

    slideFromRight.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            TranslateAnimation titleIconSlideUp = new TranslateAnimation(0, screenWidthPx/2, screenHeightPx, screenHeightPx/2);
            titleIconSlideUp.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            titleIconSlideUp.setStartOffset(500);
            titleIconSlideUp.setFillAfter(true);
            titleIconSlideUp.setDuration(1000);
            tvAnimView.startAnimation(titleIconSlideUp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    tvAnimView.startAnimation(slideFromRight);
```

the second animation inside **onAnimationEnd** is working fine. But don't know why first animation is not working fine. where my layout is simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context="broadpeak.animationlearning.AnimTestActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_anim_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213393/translate-animation You will have your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should start your animation using this line:

```
tvAnimView.startAnimation(slideFromRight);
```

Just put this piece of code in click listener or `onCreate(), onResume()` methods, according to your needs.

Comment: I forgot to post that statement Now I have also added it.And one more thing onAnimationEnd can't be called if the animation is not started